# .htaccess redirection for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Due to bug in our theme, We are trying to achieve these tasks

1.) when user click on login right now he is going to www.mysite.lu/en/wp-login.php or www.mysite.lu/fr/wp-login.php ( WPML multilingual ). For all these types of URL its showing 404 page. So we thought we can remove language from URL using .htaccess redirection method. 
So we are using following code

```
   Redirect /en/wp-login.php /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://mysite.lu/en/my-account
   Redirect /fr/wp-login.php /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://mysite.lu/fr/my-account/
   Redirect /de/wp-login.php /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://mysite.lu/de/my-account
```

using above code our login URL is working fine.

2.) But our registration URL is

```
   http://mysite.lu/en/wp-login.php?action=register
```

So when we click on register link its also redirecting to

```
   http://mysite.lu/de/my-account
```

which is incorrect. We dont want to redirect register URL.

For this we also tried below code

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)action=register($|&) [NC]
 RewriteRule  /en/wp-login\.php$ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://mysite.lu/en/my-account [L,R=301]
```

But this is also not working. 
please tell what we are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)action=register($|&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/wp-login\.php$ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://mysite.lu/$1/my-account [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

Leading slash `/` is not matched in .htaccess as it is per directory directive.

Comment: Thanks for help. 
Now strange thing is happening. URL is correct, But i am getting 404 on login

Comment: yes, Strange thing is if i comment your two lines of code then its working.

Comment: Yes, Its working if i comment your two lines of code. May be some modification needed in your code, Let me try.

Comment: Make sure this redirect rule is your very first rule. And if URL is your intended one i.e. `http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http‌​‌​‌​://mysit‌​e.‌​lu‌​/en/‌​my-a‌​ccou‌​nt` then I believe this redirect rule is working fine.

Comment: great. Its working. How we can convert this for all language like ezra tried to do

Answer (score 1):

Based in my comments and for clearer reading use this so you are not affected by RedirectMatch not being able to see past the query_string:

```
<If "! %{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^.+/"> # or ^action just for action
RedirectMatch ^/(en|fr|de)/wp-login.php$ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://mysite.lu/$1/my-account/
</If>
```

Comment: sorry, But its not working for register URL. Register URL is http://mysite.lu/en/wp-login.php?action=register

Comment: You are completely right, I misjudged that RedirectMatch won't filter or match anything after the query string, but no worries, Apache 2.4 can check that easily.
Add this:
`<If "! %{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^action/">`
`RedirectMatch ^/(en|fr|de)/wp-login.php$ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://mysite.lu/$1/my-account/`
`</If>` Find All about if in [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if)

Comment: Should you be using 2.2 you can use a RewriteCond and a RewriteRule with the same exact checks, that is a RewriteCond checking for ^action and a RewriteRule the same exact way as the redirectmatch, but using the appropiate rewrite flags at the end of the rewriterule. If you can't figure it out let me know.

Comment: One last sidenote. If you have access to the server configuration do not use .htaccesss, as it is not aimed to be some sort of "rewrites depot" as so many seem to believe. It is used only for users who have no permissions on the main configuration files. Also matching ^/ inside .htaccess wont work, it will have to be ^something instead of ^/something